# Reading and Creating a graph from excel

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, excel

I am creating a user interface that needs to read data stored in `.dat` files and plot this data onto a graph.  The `.dat` files are created daily with information stored on **per minute** basis.

The user interface will allow the user to select a date for which they need data and plot that data in a **graph**.

File 1 has certain data and File 2 has certain data.  I need to read certain data from both files and plot this data in a graph.  The files are stored on two separate computers and are stored with names `yyyymmdd_filename.dat`. The user will select their day, and two other parameters listed in the files to graph.

For the purpose of this question, how would I be able to read the data if the files were stored locally and I simply wanted to pull the data and plot it.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

If the data is always in the same spot in each file and the filenames are always the same, using the dropdown you could control the filenames in all subsequent cells.

The subsequent cells would all be made to reference the appropriate cell location in the other files on the network as long as they were always stored in the same folder.

In summary, map each field using cell references that are dynamically changed when you use the drop-down menu.

Ex. Cell A1 = 'C:\Reports[Budget.xlsx]Annual'!C10

Where A1 is the cell you want populated and C:\Reports\Budget.xlsx is the external filename and "Annual" is the sheet name within the file and C10 is the cell number within the sheet.